# pip installs my package but I'm not able to import it Python 3.10

Tags: python

when I use `pip install aiohttp` it:

```sh
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp in c:\users\ali07\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (3.7.4.post0)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in c:\users\ali07\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in c:\users\ali07\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (4.7.6)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in c:\users\ali07\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5.0,>=2.0 in c:\users\ali07\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in c:\users\ali07\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.5 in c:\users\ali07\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (3.7.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in c:\users\ali07\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in c:\users\ali07\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5.0,>=2.0 in c:\users\ali07\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.5 in c:\users\ali07\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (3.7.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in c:\users\ali07\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in c:\users\ali07\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (4.7.6)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in c:\users\ali07\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp) (2.10)
```

I know what that means it means that my package is already installed, but when I try to import it it doesn't get recognized by Visual Studio Code

I tried doing `View > Command Palette > Reload Window` that doesnt help to

Comment: Because you are installing them into Python 3.9 as can be seen from the `pip` output. Try `python3.10 -m pip install ...`.

Comment: @Selcuk That should be an answer. Maybe you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @Selcuk `python3.10 : The term 'python3.10' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again. I` I'm using windows

Comment: That was a guess. You should find out the exact command name to execute Python 3.10.

Comment: Where is your python 3.10 located? it might be missing from $PATH. If you want to use python3.10 instead of python3.9 as default you should put it before in your PATH.

Comment: @Tranbi I added it to the windows path I wanted to ask when ever a minor release comes I have do this again or only for major release

Comment: minor releases (python3.10.x) will always be installed there